# Python programming on Windows 10 for Linux environment

Tags: python, linux, windows, virtualenv

I have to use Windows 10 (company policy), but our DEV/TEST/PREPROD/PROD environments are running under Linux

I need to set up my Python (virtualenv or something similar) environment to accepting the Linux directories or paths acceptation.

Example:

```
my_directory/xxx.log

linux_path = 'my_directory/xxx.log'
windows_path = 'C\\Users\\\.....'
```

This is a bit painful to make in my code exceptions for testing in on Windows 10.

Comment: if it's only about paths: tried the `pathlib` package?

Answer (score 1):

You can use -

`os.path.join()`

to get rid of forward and back which will work on both Windows and Linux.

*Example:*

`os.path.join(my_directory,'xxx.log')`

OR

`os.sep.join()` will also work.

**Reference**

https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html

Comment: Good answer but please don't reference Python2. Support for Python2 will end with this year. `os.path.join` is in Python3 as well.

Comment: Sure, I will update my answer. Since, you didn't mentioned version and I thought of mentioned python 3

Comment: I'm not OP. ;) I just browse questions and noticed yours but with `/2/` in the link == Python2 documentation.

Comment: @h4z3 Oops :D .. .